# Doesn't Codeigniter have folders like assets and layout

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to CI. I am using version 2. I noticed like other frameworks CI didn't have folders like assets and layout. Where do i place files like css and js and images. Also where is the layout folder.

Comment: look into Phil Sturgeons template library, and CI Sprinkles library first is for layout/theme/partials management, second is for asset management js/css minification and caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place your assets directory wherever you desire, putting it under the root CodeIgniter directory is usually the norm.

CodeIgniter has no reason to include an assets directory as that's usually a front-end requirement, of which CI isn't made for (it's a back end MVC framework).

Comment: what do u mean by "root CI directory"

Comment: When you download CodeIgniter you'll the main directoy will have the file `index.php` and directories such as `application` and `system`, this is the root of the CI directory. Put your assets directory here, won't cause any harm.

Answer (score 1):

a simple answer is **no**. CI don't have that. You need to manually create.

And if you are coming from Yii, Ci doesn't implement that feature of Layout.

**EDIT**

by default, CI doesn't have. You can tweak it but easier implementation is

```
$this->load->view('header', $param1);
$this->load->view('content', $param2);
$this->load->view('footer', $param3);
```

where param1, param2, .... are variables you want to pass it to view.

CI will add the views in that order.

and remember, don't put `.php` while at the end of the filename in `view()`.

Answer (score 0):

### No

Is the simple answer, you have to extend CIs functionality and use a library from a third party to provide these features for you. CI doesn't focus on the aesthetics of the "front-end". Its primary focus was "back-end".

### Your Options:

look into Phil Sturgeons template library, and CI Sprinkles library first is for layout/theme/partials management, second is for asset management js/css minification and caching.

Phil's Template Library: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/

Sprinkles Library: https://github.com/edmundask/Sprinkle

#### Or build your own basic template library

This is a great intro video how to do such. I have used this in the past, before i got into using Sparks.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvGymDhY49E

#### you can use Sparks to make lib management a bit easier

In 2.1 sparks aren't included however it is in the dev builds of CI so im sure at a later date it will be merged in with the base code. FOr now you can use this site to install Sparks to help you manage third party libraries.

http://getsparks.org

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a template library.

You don't have to programmatically serve the CSS and JS it can just be part of a view file.

But, you can if you want to!  CI is incredibly flexible.  We've written our own template library that works great for us (we'll release it soon, just checking that it works how we want it to...) but it might not suit the way you work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this PHP layout manager library, can be integrated with codeigniter easily:

https://github.com/mahadazad/php-layout-manager

its easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 0):

look for assets helper to load css and js file anywhere..

[Simple assets helper for codeigniter](https://github.com/grigoris86/codeigniter-simple-assets-helper.git)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.